# Passing a variable from an activity to a non-activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, filenames, filepath

In my Main Activity, I have this part which contains the filepath and the filename of the choosen file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private static File selectedFile;

public static File Filename;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch(requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_PICK_FILE:

            if(data.hasExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH)) {

                selectedFile = new File
                        (data.getStringExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH));
                filePath.setText(selectedFile.getPath());  
            }
            break;
        }
    }
} //onActivityResult

//and i added this so that I will be able to save the filepath and access it from my CoordinatesXmlParser.java (a non-activity class)

public void Filename () {
String filename = selectedFile.toString();

//return selectedFile;
}
}
```

And then on my CoordinatesXmlParser.java, I have this part:

```
File file = MainActivity.Filename;
file.toString();

//String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/XML/coordinates.xml";
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

Problem: It is trowing a NullPointException. How would I be able to pass the filepath from the MainActivity.java to the CoordinatesXmlParser.java? TIA

Comment: where you are using `CoordinatesXmlParser` in `MainActivity` ?

Comment: pardon? i did not seem to understand your question.

Comment: I mean in which class you are using `CoordinatesXmlParser` class for parsing xml?

Comment: yes Sir. Sorry if I did not get the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns Null because in any moment you have assigned any value to the variable Filename (which by the way, goes against the patterns: variables should not begin with upper case letters).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private static File selectedFile;

public static File Filename;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch(requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_PICK_FILE:

            if(data.hasExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH)) {

                selectedFile = new File
                        (data.getStringExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH));
                filePath.setText(selectedFile.getPath());  
            }
            break;
        }
    }
} //onActivityResult

//and i added this so that I will be able to save the filepath and access it from my CoordinatesXmlParser.java (a non-activity class)
     public static String getFilename () {
         return selectedFile.toString();
     }
}
```

And then

```
File file = MainActivity.getFilename();
file.toString();
```

Also, it is important to notice that this is not a good idea at all. You should only call getFilename() after you are sure that "onActivityResult" has already been called, otherwise it will always raise a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line will throw a NullPointException

> File file = MainActivity.Filename;

if you want to pass the filepath from the MainActivity.java to the CoordinatesXmlParser.java,you can use Application Class to achieve this.

In your Application Class,you can write two methods

```
 private String fileName;


public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}


public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
```

then in your MainActivity  call setFileName method,and in your CoordinatesXmlParser  call get getFileName method.